# Not able to retrieve hidden field value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have stored list in hidden field.

```
<input id="ProductList" name="ProductList" type="hidden" value="[{&quot;ProductDetailsID&quot;:303,&quot;Size&quot;:&quot;S&quot;,&quot;Color&quot;:&quot;White&quot;,&quot;SizeID&quot;:9,&quot;ColorID&quot;:11,&quot;MRP&quot;:2,&quot;SellingPrice&quot;:5,&quot;StockQuantity&quot;:5,&quot;ImageCount&quot;:1,&quot;IsDiscountPercent&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;ProductDiscount&quot;:0,&quot;ProductList&quot;:null}]">
```

I am trying to retrieve value using JQuery

```
$('#ProductList').val()
```

but I am getting list type instead of actual list value

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebYedaz.Models.Data.Product.ProductDetails]
```

The hidden field has proper value when i inspect the DOM but still not able to retrieve it. what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Your ID is different then your written ID for fetching value.

Please update with below:

`$("#ProductList").val();`

Comment: Would it not be more correct to vote this as a type error, and post the correct value in the comment section?

Comment: I'll take care next time sir

Comment: even after using $("#ProductList").val() I am not able to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong id in the Jquery code. I think you should try using `$('#ProductList').val()` instead of $('#List').val().

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var value = $('#ProductList').val();
console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ProductList" name="ProductList" type="hidden" value="[{&quot;ProductDetailsID&quot;:303,&quot;Size&quot;:&quot;S&quot;,&quot;Color&quot;:&quot;White&quot;,&quot;SizeID&quot;:9,&quot;ColorID&quot;:11,&quot;MRP&quot;:2,&quot;SellingPrice&quot;:5,&quot;StockQuantity&quot;:5,&quot;ImageCount&quot;:1,&quot;IsDiscountPercent&quot;:&quot;%&quot;,&quot;ProductDiscount&quot;:0,&quot;ProductList&quot;:null}]">
```